# Message truncation on submit SM

Tags: sms, smpp

Please advise why a message is getting truncated on submit sm. The message being submitted by the ESME is around 259 characters, However, what is reaching the SMSC is around 13o characters, with some content truncated. I can share the TCP dump if need be

regards

I tried increasing the maximum message fragments on the smsc but it still did not resolve the issue

Comment: I don't understand what is the flow. Esme is on SMSC so which part is truncating ?
Upload tcp somewhere so I can see.

Comment: Thanks Marvin for the concern. It worked by adding UDH in the request string